# Is it possible to define [Int] * Int using custom operator in Swift?

Tags: swift, operator-overloading, operators

I want to define a new operator and multiply each element of the array `[Int]` by `Int`, such as `[3, 2, 10] * 10`.

However, because `Int` is neither protocol nor class (it's struct), I first defined the following:

```
protocol Numeric {}
extension Int: Numeric {}
extension Double: Numeric {}
extension Float: Numeric {}
```

And then, I tried defining the operator, like:

```
func *<T: Numeric> (left: [T], right: T) -> [T] {
    var newArray: [T] = []
    for i in left {
        newArray.append(i * right)
    }

    return newArray
}
```

However, this spits out an error: `Cannot convert value of type 'T' to expected argument type '[_]'`.

I'm not sure what the type `[_]` means, which I don't *expect*, but I guess the problem comes from that I don't have an operator defined that takes `T` and `T`, both of which are `Numeric` in this case.

So I defined another operator, like:

```
func *<T: Numeric> (left: T, right: T) -> T {
    return left * right
}
```

However, while this has been compiled without problems, the runtime error occurred with a lot of a lot of `static * infix <A where ...> (A, A) -> A`.

[image]

I'm not sure why this operator was executed so many times, but now I wonder if it is possible in the first place to define a custom `*` operator, although the `Int` does already have `*` operator defined.

So is it still possible to define `[Int] * Int` operator in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to require the multiplication operation in the `Numeric`
protocol:

```
protocol Numeric {
    func *(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}
```

Otherwise the multiplication in `newArray.append(i * right)` is
not defined.

Your

```
func *<T: Numeric> (left: T, right: T) -> T {
    return left * right
}
```

(which calls itself recursively, resulting in a stack overflow) is then not needed.

The implementation of your new operator itself can be simplified
(as already described in a now deleted answer) to

```
func *<T: Numeric> (left: [T], right: T) -> [T] {
    return left.map { $0 * right }
}
```

Comment: Ooooh it's super awesome. Well I first tried to define it using map, but after I hit the wall, I made it more simple to make sure the problem doesn't come from `map`. Thanks so much.